# Comparing nested values of dictionary without key importance

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary as the following:

```
Dict = {
         1: {
              "a": {some more nested data},
              "b": {some more nested data},
              "c": {some more nested data}
            },
         2: {
              "a": {some more nested data},
              "b": {some more nested data},
              "c": {some more nested data}
            },
         3: {
              "a": {some more nested data},
              "b": {some more nested data},
              "c": {some more nested data}
            },
         4: {
              "a": {some more nested data},
              "b": {some more nested data},
              "c": {some more nested data}
            },
         5: {
              "a": {some more nested data},
              "b": {some more nested data},
              "c": {some more nested data}
            },
         6: {
              "a": {some more nested data},
              "b": {some more nested data},
              "c": {some more nested data}
            }
       }
```

I want to make function which compares if nested data from positions 1-3 is same as 4-5, where positions can be changed. So values can be same in 1 and 4, 2 and 5, 3 and 6, but also same data in 1 and 5, 2 and 4, 3 and 6.

Function should return True if data on positions 1-3 is same as in positions 4-6 and False if not.

Is there any way to do it, which is more elegant than for loop with a lot of ifs?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
def func():
    return list(Dict.values())[:3] == list(Dict.values())[3:6]
```

Comment: i think some sorting is needed

Comment: Permutations maybe? e.g. compare the first entry-set with every permutation of the second entry-set. Something along the lines of `any(list(Dict.values())[:3] == list(p) for p in permutations(list(Dict.values())[3:6]))` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

[Masklinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8182118/masklinn) answer was working great. I just updated it with situations, where one of the position dicts (1-3 and 4-6) can be popped.

```
any(list(v for k, v in Dict.items() if k in range(1, 4)) ==
    list(p) for p in itertools.permutations(
    list(v for k, v in Dict.items() if k in range(4, 7))))
```